# How to get all embedded mongoid documents for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid4

In Mongoid (Rails) I have 3 models: *File*, *Version* and *User*. *Version* is embedded_in *File*, and both *File* and *Version* belongs_to a *User* (though not necessarily the same for all *Version*s in a *File*).

Now I want to retrieve all *Version*s that either belong to a specific *User*, or are embedded in a *File* that belongs to the same *User*.

I have tried:

1. Pretty much anything `Version.<something>`, always 0 results (probably because *Version* is not a top level document?)
2. `File.any_of(user: user, 'versions.user': user)`: NoMethodError: undefined method `bson_type' for #<User:0x00000007cd9400>
3. `File.any_of(user: user, 'versions.user_id': user.id)`: Only returns *File*s that belong to the *User*, not *File*s that embed *Version*s belonging to the user

How can this be achieved in a database friendly way (not fetching all *File*s and iterating through their *Version*s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'Embedded', that means the embedded model (Version) is no longer an individual entity and has no separate [collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-collection). It is included as a part of the [Document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document) (File model object).

No collection implies ->
Pt 1 will return nil

Pt2 It also implies that the User - Version relationship doesn't exist

In Pt3 the 'versions.user_id' query is simply ignored.

Re: "How can this be achieved in a database friendly way?"

Embedded documents are used only when they are never meant to be used independently or are meaningless without the context of parent document.
So the only way to access and embedded doc is [through](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) the parent doc.

Since Version here is being used by both File and User, you should consider creating a separate collection for it. (aka Normalized Data Models)

You can read up some more on mongodb data modelling [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/)